# Where to put "mysql_real_escape_string" in this code?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I've looked at other examples on here, but everyone else's syntax is different from what I have, so I have no clue where to put "mysql_real_escape_string".
Here is my current code:

```
include("dbconnect.php");

mysql_select_db("scratch", $con);

$sql= "INSERT INTO stories (author, story_name, story)

VALUES 
('$_POST[author]','$_POST[story_name]', '$_POST[story]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Story Submitted!";

mysql_close($con)
```

Where would I add that string in this?

Comment: Instead of such a question, upgrade yourself to use parametrized queries/prepared statements. Atleast use Mysqli instead of this obsolete mysql extension

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape any variable values you're including in your query. So in your code these would be:

- `$_POST['author']`
- `$_POST['story_name']`
- `$_POST['story']`

So change your `$sql` variable to look like:

```
$author     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
$story_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story_name']);
$story      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story']);

$sql= "
INSERT INTO stories (author, story_name, story)
VALUES ('$author','$story_name', '$story')
";
```

You should probably also add `isset` or `empty` checks when using the `$_POST` variables to avoid notices if they don't exist. Finally, you'd be better served to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with prepared statements than the less robust mysql extension.

Answer (score 1):

//USE IN THIS WAY THE QUERY WILL RUN PROPERLY WITH mysql_real_escape_string

```
$sql= 'INSERT INTO stories (author, story_name, story)
   VALUES  
   ('.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[author]).',
     '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[story_name]).',
     '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[story]).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

put POST variables into new variables and then apply mysql_real_escape_string, and finally put new variables into the SQL statement

Here's the code:

```
include("dbconnect.php");

mysql_select_db("scratch", $con);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[author]);
$story_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[story_name]);
$story=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[story]);

$sql= "INSERT INTO stories (author, story_name, story)

VALUES 
('$author','$story_name', '$story')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
echo "Story Submitted!";

mysql_close($con);
```